# Wordpress не видит все записи

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Написал такой код в единственном файле index.php и создал 2 записи, но WordPress не отображает всех записей. Почему?

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) : 
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2> 
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile;

else :
    echo '<p>No content found</p>';

endif;
?>
```

А вот у него [все работает](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7olvEeBM2I).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен.Проста надо было зайти в настройки->чтение и там изменить Страница записей (у меня было пусто) на главную страницу ну или на котором хотите чтобы все посты были видны (в моем случае это страница Home).[image]